# Aggregate on joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I m using the following query, to get the result as shown below. Actually the query is just joining 2 tables.

```
SELECT MT.mkt_Area_ID,MA.mkt_Reg_ID,MT.mktcate_id,MT.target_Amt,MT.year 
FROM [CRM].[tblMktArea_Target] MT JOIN CRM.tblMarketingArea MA 
ON MA.mkt_Area_ID= MT.mkt_Area_ID WHERE month IN (05,04) AND year=2013 AND MA.mkt_Area_ID=1 
AND MA.mkt_Reg_ID =1
```

[image]

How can I group the results by mktcate_id to get the sum of target_amt for each category?

I tried:

```
SELECT MT.mkt_Area_ID,MA.mkt_Reg_ID,MT.mktcate_id,Sum(MT.target_Amt),MT.year 
    FROM [CRM].[tblMktArea_Target] MT JOIN CRM.tblMarketingArea MA 
    ON MA.mkt_Area_ID= MT.mkt_Area_ID WHERE month IN (05,04) AND year=2013 AND MA.mkt_Area_ID=1 
    AND MA.mkt_Reg_ID =1 group by MT.mktcate_id
```

and getting errror

Comment: are columns `MT.mkt_Area_ID and MA.mkt_Reg_ID` important in the final result set?

Comment: Just  remove the extra columns from the select which are not in the group by statement. Remove `MT.mkt_Area_ID, MA.mkt_Reg_ID, MT.year`

Comment: @Meherzad I need MT.mkt_Area_ID, MA.mkt_Reg_ID in the result set

Comment: @JW웃 yes. I need them in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an exception because it is necessary to add non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. Example,

```
SELECT MT.mkt_area_id, 
       MA.mkt_reg_id, 
       MT.mktcate_id, 
       SUM(MT.target_amt), 
       MT.year 
FROM   [CRM].[TBLMKTAREA_TARGET] MT 
       JOIN CRM.TBLMARKETINGAREA MA 
         ON MA.mkt_area_id = MT.mkt_area_id 
WHERE  month IN ( 05, 04 ) 
       AND year = 2013 
       AND MA.mkt_area_id = 1 
       AND MA.mkt_reg_id = 1 
GROUP  BY   MT.mktcate_id, 
            MT.mkt_area_id, 
            MA.mkt_reg_id,
            MT.year
```

Answer (score 1):

You should always GROUP BY on all the columns that are not within aggregate functions (such as SUM, MAX, AVG).
Put MT.mkt_Area_ID, MA.mkt_Reg_ID, MT.year fields into the GROUP BY clause:

```
 SELECT MT.mkt_Area_ID,
           MA.mkt_Reg_ID,
           MT.mktcate_id,
           Sum(MT.target_Amt),
           MT.year 
      FROM [CRM].[tblMktArea_Target] MT JOIN CRM.tblMarketingArea MA ON 
              MA.mkt_Area_ID = MT.mkt_Area_ID 
     WHERE month IN (05,04) AND 
           year = 2013 AND 
           MA.mkt_Area_ID = 1 AND 
           MA.mkt_Reg_ID = 1 
  GROUP BY MT.mktcate_id,
           MT.mkt_Area_ID,
           MA.mkt_Reg_ID,
           MT.year
```

Or remove MT.mkt_Area_ID, MA.mkt_Reg_ID, MT.year fields from the SELECT clause:

```
 SELECT MT.mktcate_id,
           Sum(MT.target_Amt)
     FROM [CRM].[tblMktArea_Target] MT JOIN CRM.tblMarketingArea MA ON 
            MA.mkt_Area_ID = MT.mkt_Area_ID 
     WHERE month IN (05,04) AND 
           year = 2013 AND 
           MA.mkt_Area_ID = 1 AND 
           MA.mkt_Reg_ID = 1 
  GROUP BY MT.mktcate_id
```